# Date localization with nanoc's "created_at"

Tags: ruby, date, localization, internationalization, nanoc

I found lot of articles talking about i18n with Rails, Nanoc, but nothing about a really simple (I think) thing: how to internationalize a date on a nanoc article.

I have a really simple setup, for example here is a snippet of my index.html page:

```
<%= link_to(post[:title], post.path) %> - <%= post[:created_at] %>
```

This is a dummy article:

```
---
title: Test
created_at: 1 January 1970
---
```

Wich gives this result when compiled:

```
Test - 1 January 1970
```

But I would like the date to be in French, like this:

```
Test - 1 Janvier 1970
```

Comment: This question is specifically about Nanoc, but any Ruby solution would be appreciated. This is _NOT_ a Rails issue. But yes, I've read the Rails i18n documentation, sadly it does not apply in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rails' internationalization gem, [`i18n`](http://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n), on its own for this task. Here's a simple example:

1. If you're using Bundler, edit your nanoc project's `Gemfile` to include the `i18n` gem:

   ```
   gem 'i18n'
   ```

   Otherwise, install the gem locally on your computer (for which you'll probably need superuser privileges):

   ```
   gem install i18n
   ```
2. Add a French translation file at, say, `tr/fr.yml`, to your nanoc project. Place in it these (minimal) contents:

   ```
   ---
   fr:
     date:
       formats:
         default: ! '%-d %B %Y'
       month_names:
       - 
       - janvier
       - février
       - mars
       - avril
       - mai
       - juin
       - juillet
       - août
       - septembre
       - octobre
       - novembre
       - décembre
   ```
3. Add a helper for performing the translation, for instance at `lib/translate_date.rb`, with this code:

   ```
    require 'date'
    require 'i18n'

    # Load our translation files
    I18n.load_path = Dir['./tr/*.yml']

    # Set the default locale to French
    I18n.locale = :fr

    # Translates a date string into the default locale.
    def translate_date(date)
      I18n.l Date.parse(date, '%d %B %Y')
    end
   ```
4. Now place this in your `index.html` file,

   ```
   <%= link_to(post[:title], post.path) %> - <%= translate_date(post[:created_at]) %>
   ```

   and you should get the output you want.

Comment: It does exactly want I wanted to do, thanks. I just added `I18n.enforce_available_locales = false` after requiring the i18n Gem to silence the warning when compiling since I'm not going to use any other locale than French.